# SortedList Performance - how does the sorted list sort itself?

Tags: c#, sorting, sortedlist

I am trying to find out more details about the sorted list so that I can analyze whether it will perform like I need it to in several specific situations.

Does anyone know the specific sorting algorithm that it uses to sort its elements?

Answer (score 7):

`SortedList<T,U>` uses an array internally for its keys, and performs the "sort" by inserting the items on `Add` in the correct order.  When you call `Add` with a new item, it does a `Array.BinarySearch` with an `Array.Insert`.

This is why it has these [characteristics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132330.aspx):

> This method is an O(n) operation for unsorted data, where n is Count. It is an O(log n) operation if the new element is added at the end of the list. If insertion causes a resize, the operation is O(n).

Comment: [Big O (O(n), O(log n), etc.) notation explained](http://bigocheatsheet.com/) for those who are not aware